# How to create a new table with nested data in big query from another tables?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata

I found lots of example to create nested data in google bigquery manual but there is no example to do this from another tables.

I want to create a new table (for example solar_system_moons_nested) with nested data (write SQL statement to generate the nested data) using two existing tables (for example planets and moons tables).  I want the new table look as follows:

[image]

I create the moon and planet tables as below:

1. moon table

[image]

2. planet table:

[image]

Is there anyway to create a nested table from existing tables? any help would be appreciated.

Here is how I made the new table(as below):

```
WITH solar_system_moons_nested AS (
  SELECT p.planet,
          STRUCT(moon ,Distance_from_Planet__km_,Diameter__km_) AS moons, 
          from test.planets p inner join test.moons m on m.planet=p.planet
)

select * from solar_system_moons_nested
```

and here is how it look like:
[image]

As you see, the select did not do what I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is a nested structure, you can use array_agg and do something like below

```sql
WITH solar_system_moons_nested AS (
  SELECT p.planet,
          ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(moon ,Distance_from_Planet__km_,Diameter__km_)) AS moons, 
          from test.planets p inner join test.moons m on m.planet=p.planet
  GROUP BY 1
)

select * from solar_system_moons_nested
```

More on array_agg here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_agg](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg) to construct an array:

```
WITH solar_system_moons_nested AS (
  SELECT 
    p.planet,
    array_agg(STRUCT(moon ,Distance_from_Planet__km_,Diameter__km_)) AS moons, 
  from test.planets p inner join test.moons m on m.planet=p.planet
  group by p.planet
)

select * from solar_system_moons_nested
```